# Switch DB implementation details at runtime using the repository pattern in a Clean architecture project

Tags: rust, transactions, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

This is just an example of an *(still incomplete)* real-world project written in Rust using a [clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html): https://github.com/frederikhors/rust-clean-architecture-with-db-transactions.

#### Goals

My intent is to have an app build in 4 layers:

- `entities`:

  - *some call this layer "domain"*, not important for now, just the minimum
- `services`:

  - *some call this layer "use cases"*, this is where business logic lives (just CRUD methods for now)
- `repositories`:

  - *some call this layer "adapters"*, this is where concrete implementation of DB/cache/mail drivers lives
- `ports`:

  - *some call this layer "controllers or presenters"*, still not present and not important for now, I'm using `main.rs` for this

#### Reproduction

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/frederikhors/rust-clean-architecture-with-db-transactions/main

#### The issue

If you open the [`main.rs`](https://github.com/frederikhors/rust-clean-architecture-with-db-transactions/blob/main/src/main.rs#L18-L38) file you can see the issue:

```rust
// This obviously works if alone:
// let db_repo = Arc::new(repositories::in_memory::Repo::new());

// This obviously works if alone:
// let pg_pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres").await.unwrap());
// let db_repo = Arc::new(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool));

// This doesn't work instead:
let db_repo = if use_postgres {
    let pg_pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres").await.unwrap());

    Arc::new(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool))
} else {
    Arc::new(repositories::in_memory::Repo::new())
};
```

My intent here is to change repository in use based on a variable, but Rust doesn't like it, this is the error:

Expand the error

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
--> src\main.rs:37:9
|
28 |       let db_repo = if use_postgres {
|  ___________________-
29 | |         let pg_pool = Arc::new(
30 | |             sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres")
31 | |                 .await
...  |
35 | |         Arc::new(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool))
| |         ---------------------------------------------------- expected because of this
36 | |     } else {
37 | |         Arc::new(repositories::in_memory::Repo::new())
| |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `repositories::postgres::Repo`, found struct `in_memory::Repo`
38 | |     };
| |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
|
= note: struct `in_memory::Repo` and struct `repositories::postgres::Repo` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: struct `in_memory::Repo` is defined in module `crate::repositories::in_memory` of the current crate
--> src\repositories\in_memory\mod.rs:6:1
|
6  | pub struct Repo {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: struct `repositories::postgres::Repo` is defined in module `crate::repositories::postgres` of the current crate
--> src\repositories\postgres\mod.rs:6:1
|
6  | pub struct Repo {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Like always with different types you have essentialy 2 options, static or dynamic dispatch.

For dynamic dispatch both `Repo` types have to implement a common trait that encompasses all necessary functionality and is object safe:

```rust
pub trait Repo {
    fn do_stuff_with_repo(&self);
    // etc
}

impl Repo for postgres::Repo {
    fn do_stuff_with_repo(&self) {
        //...
    }
}

impl Repo for in_memory::Repo {
    fn do_stuff_with_repo(&self) {
        //...
    }
}

let db_repo: Arc<dyn Repo> = if use_postgres {
    let pg_pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres").await.unwrap());

    Arc::new(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool))
} else {
    Arc::new(repositories::in_memory::Repo::new())
};
```

or for static dispatch create an `enum` and everytime you have to deal with it you pattern match:

```rust
enum Repo {
    Memory(in_memory::Repo),
    Postgres(postgres::Repo),
}
let db_repo = if use_postgres {
    let pg_pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres").await.unwrap());

    Arc::new(Repo::Postgres(repositories::postgres::Repo::new(pg_pool)))
} else {
    Arc::new(Repo::Memory(repositories::in_memory::Repo::new()))
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue with this project using dynamic dispatch is that I'm using `pub commands_repo: Arc<C>` which comes from `pub fn new_executor<C: RepoTrait + Send + Sync + 'static>(deps: Arc<Deps<C>>) -> Box<dyn Executor> {...}`. I cannot use as you suggest `let db_repo: Arc<dyn Repo>`. Or at least I don't know how to do. I'm fixing the codesandbox reproduction so you can execute the code there easily.

Comment: This is the branch with static dispatch, also in error with your suggestions: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/frederikhors/rust-clean-architecture-with-db-transactions/static-dispatch-for-db_repo. I do not understand the error.

Comment: Even if I change `pub queries_repo: Arc<dyn queries::RepoTrait>` to `pub queries_repo: Arc<C>` I still get many errors like: `the trait bound Repo: services::commands::RepoPlayer is not satisfied`. Why @cafce25?

Comment: Probably because the trait bound `RepoPlayer` is not satisfied. Or in other words you did not implement `RepoPlayer` for whatever type you get that error on or did not specify that bound on the trait object.

Comment: This is all implemented. In fact if you use them alone they work!

Comment: A `dyn queries::RepoTrait` only implements `RepoTrait` and all bounds defined on that trait.

Comment: I think you @cafce25 are telling me to do `impl RepoPlayer for Repo {}` (the enum Repo in this case), right? But then I should repeat again all the methods, right?

Comment: You can probably just make it a supertrait: `trait RepoTrait: RepoPlayer` if it's implemented for the datatype already.

Comment: Can you please explain the latest phrase? What do you mean by requiring the enum?

Comment: I saw you wrote `supertrait` now, but how? On the `enum`?

Comment: I already have a supertrait: `pub trait RepoTrait: Send + Sync + RepoPlayer + RepoTeam {}`...